# Using stanford parser to parse Chinese

Tags: stanford-nlp

here is my code, mostly from the demo. The program runs perfectly, but the result is very wrong. It did not spilt the words. 
Thank you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/xinhuaFactored.ser.gz");

  demoAPI(lp);

}


public static void demoAPI(LexicalizedParser lp) {


// This option shows loading and using an explicit tokenizer
String sent2 = "我爱你";
TokenizerFactory<CoreLabel> tokenizerFactory =
    PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "");
Tokenizer<CoreLabel> tok =
    tokenizerFactory.getTokenizer(new StringReader(sent2));
List<CoreLabel> rawWords2 = tok.tokenize();

Tree parse = lp.apply(rawWords2);

TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
List<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();
System.out.println(tdl);
System.out.println();

// You can also use a TreePrint object to print trees and dependencies
TreePrint tp = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");
tp.printTree(parse);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure to segment the words? For example try running it again with "我 爱 你." as the sentence. I believe from the command line the parser will segment automatically, however I'm not sure what it does from within Java.